# I want to read data from two excel sheets to one excel sheet with button using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w87h2.jpg)I want to read data from two sheets whereas user will enter only date and after clicking button data will be populated in sheet.

[image: this is requirement that i want]

Title                    Date
Enter Week Start Date   "7/11/2016" (Button)

Name    Project-ID  Project Name    Project Start Date  Project End Date    Sum Sum * 20

This is actual format of requirement.

Comment: Sub searchdata()
Dim erow As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As String
Dim count As Integer

lastrow = Sheets("Config_InputAllocation_Weekly").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If Sheets("Config_InputAllocation_Weekly").Cells(x, 3) = Sheet1.Range("B2") Then
Sheet1.Range("A5") = Sheets("Config_InputAllocation_Weekly").Cells(x, 3)
Sheet1.Range("B5") = Sheets("Config_InputAllocation_Weekly").Cells(x, 7)
Sheet1.Range("C5") = Sheets("Config_InputAllocation_Weekly").Cells(x, 8)

End If
End Sub

Comment: Can anybody help me for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

in your line

```
Set objsheet = bjExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Config_InputAllocation_Weekly") 
Set objsheet2 = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Config_Project")
```

you try to set both sheets active, which is not possible. There only be one active sheet. But you don't have to set them active. Use the following technique:

```
Dim objExcel as Object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

Dim myWb as workbook, myws1 as worksheet, myWs2 as worksheet
Set myWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ABC\Documents\NSL\Automation Macro\NSL_DM_Tracker.xlsm") 
Set myWs1 = myWb.Worksheets("Config_InputAllocation_Weekly")
Set myWs2 = myWb.Worksheets("Config_Project")
```

Then you can easily call the data from both sheets whether they are active or not:

```
Msgbox myWs1.Cells(1,1).value
Msgbox myWs2.Cells(1,1).value
```

Then the other problem is that you have defined an Sub `searchdata()` but it is not called within your `CommandButton1_Click()` Sub.

Moreover use Option Explicit setting, that is, put this line at the very top of your code:

```
Option Explicit
```

This will help you to debug your code.
Last but not least, in your Sub `searchdata()` no Worksheets are defined. Thus it will not know which one (myWs1 or myWs2) to use and when.

Good Luck,
Viktor